# is it possible to store only the day(d) of date in database regardless of month and year?

Tags: php, date

Here what I've tried so far:

```
$date = date("d",$_REQUEST[]);
```

Is that code right?

Comment: does that even compile? try `$date = date("d",$_REQUEST["timestamp"]);`, and call it with the query `?timestamp=1234567`, should give you the day of month for the given unix timestamp. Or just `$date = date("d")` which will give you todays day of the month.

Comment: yes, **2.** you probably will regret some time very soon if the month and year is omitted

Comment: $date = date("d",$_REQUEST['date']);

Comment: Er, I think `$_REQUEST[]` just returns `null`.

Comment: Ewwww, who upvoted this question?

Answer (score 1):

You will then need to have a field of data type "TINYINT" in that database table.

Hope it helps.